# Blue Background invades White Background in SE profile

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

I was looking at a user's SE profile to see if the caching has stopped and for some reason there is a blue background behind the badges, answers, and questions. Normally it is white if I am in full screen, but it is blue if I shrink my screen down:

[image]

No I didn't highlight that area because if I do, it turns dark blue instead.

Comment: Shrink your screen to about that size and see if you can repro that

Comment: That was a long time ago... Good memories. Anyways, don't be such a critic!

Comment: @rene lol, why not? :D

Comment: Yes. Everyone loves Disney, me especially. Don't worry :)

Comment: very strange bug, very nice find